# apt-get fails to continue running in a loop after one failed install in bash

Tags: bash, apt-get

I am trying to create a bash script that will automatically install stuff using apt-get.  I am using the following methods for the installation:

Method 1

```
Install(){
for TempVar in "$1"
do
eval 'sudo apt-get install '$TempVar
done
}
```

Method 2

```
Install(){
eval 'sudo apt-get install '$TempVar
}

for TempVar in "$1"
do
Install '(insert programs here separated by spaces)'
done
```

In both cases when something failed to install apt-get refused to install anything else.  Naturally, apt-get functioned normally in the same script after the for loop ended.  I am under the impression that apt-get retains its error status until the loop it was executed in is fully terminated.  Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: please click on http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27219398/edit and format your code as code, so we know what's code and what's plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your code fails because you do all the installations in *one* apt-get command.  And apt-get processes arguments given to it one-by-one.  so when one of the arguments fails, then all that follows will be ignored.

So, In your calling code, you give it just one argument, namely the quoted string 'pkg1 pkg2 pk3':

```
Install 'pkg1 pgk2 pkg3'
```

then in your function, eval takes the one argument string, and turns it into a *single* apt-get command with 3 package arguments.

I just wrote and tested the following.  I think it is what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

function my_install() {
    for p in "$@"
    do
    sudo apt-get --yes install $p
    done
}


# here, call:
# my_install pkg1 pkg2 pkg3
```

Notice, I don't quote my package list arguments to my function.  Also note, I use "$@" in my for loop.

Answer (score 1):

both your loops install only one package with each call to apt-get.  It's not apt-get that is stopping the loop on error, it's bash, because each apt-get is running as a separate command.

I think what you wanted was

```
sudo apt-get install $1
```

Edit: also, if you quote "$1" it will create a single long package name containing spaces, which is probably not what you want.  If your script arguments contain spaces, use "$@" (with quotes around it).  $@ will reproduce the script args as received, with spaces in the right places.

Comment: Actually, that is not the problem.  To clarify, everything appears to install just fine as long as an installation does not fail.  The problem is when one installation fails apt-get does not try to install anything else that the loop directs it to in the script until after the loop has terminated and stops running.  This does not seem to affect apt-get outside of the loop in the same script.

Comment: However, you may have a point:  putting double quotes around the $1 may not be required if the input is a variable.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention:  Everything installs once I edit out the mistyped or no longer existent package from the variable, my main concern is this can lead to issues later on in a full script since package names could eventually change and I would rather not have parts of my script that are not dependent on the package fail because of it.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have already pointed out, your quoting is off. In fact, the loops are redundant, because `for anything in "$1"` will always execute the loop body exactly one.

That can be fixed by using `for anything in "$@"` but in fact, I think your apprach is wrong. Simply add one option;

```
sudo apt-get install --ignore-missing list of packages without quotes
```